# How do I avoid launching dialogfragment when EditText loses focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-dialogfragment

I have a OnFocusChangeListener on an EditText line that launches a dialogfragment to allow the user to select a date from a Datepicker.
When I click "Set" on the DialogFragment, the selected date is set in the EditText.  Focus is on the EditText line with the cursor blinking at the beginning of the date that was set.

As soon as I click to another EditText line on the UI screen, the DialogFragment launches again, which I don't want.  Basically I want to launch the DialogFragment when the EditText initially gains focus and after setting the date, I want the OnFocusChangeListener to ignore when the EditText loses focus as the user moves the cursor and focus to another EditText line on the screen.  Please advise.

Here is partial code in Activity.java file:

```
    ...
    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
```

Here is partial code in DatePickerFragment.java file:

```
    ...
    // Puts the selected date into the EditText line.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
    String date=(month+1) + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    txtDate.setText(date);
    }

    // When the dialog date is set the dialogfragment closes and the softkeboard re-loads back on the CardViewActivity.
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CardViewActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // The soft keyboard always closes when the DialogFragment is displayed.  So the
    // line below toggles the soft keyboard to show again.
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have forgot to put a check of "if `editText` having focus or not". Do as following

```
  fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if(hasFocus){
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }
      else {
         // do nothing
       }
    }
});
```

It will launch your `DialogFragment` only when `editText` gains focus and will do nothing focus lose.

Comment: That works.  But how do I interpret the addition (hasFocus)?  It says if the EditText gains focus launch the DialogFragment but if the EditText loses focus then the statement is not true so don't launch the DialogFragment?  Sorry I am new to coding.

Comment: Ok. Do I need the else {  //do nothing } function?  Should it be a null function or similar?

Comment: that was just for understanding. you can remove the else part. Or if you want to perform something else on focus lose you can do over there.

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate your replies and explanations, cheers!